# Samba package failed to install via button

Tags: software-installation, samba, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.1

The first thing I did after that was install wsdd.

The second thing I did was attempt to share the desktop folder.

When I pressed the "Install Samba" button it reported: "The Samba package failed to install"

Did wsdd tangle with Samba and prevent it from installing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully installed Samba via `sudo apt install samba`

I never got that "Install Samba" button to work, even after removing wsdd.